# Sales commission program using while loop. Value not updating

Tags: python, while-loop, updating

My while loop isn't updating my new sales commission program eveerytime I run the program. Here is my program:

```
 #this program calculates sales commissions and sums the total of all sales commissions the user has entered

print("Welcom to the program sales commission loop")

keep_going='y'

while keep_going=='y':

    #get a salespersons sales and commission rate
    sales=float(input('Enter the amount of sales'))
    comm_rate=float(input('Enter commission rate'))

    total=0

    #calculate the commission
    commission=sales*comm_rate



    print("commission is",commission)



    keep_going=input('Enter y for yes')

    total=total+commission
    print("Total is",total)

print("You have exited the program. Thet total is",total)
```

Here is the output of the program: Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25          2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

> > > 

```
Welcom to the program sales commission loop
Enter the amount of sales899
Enter commission rate.09
commission is 80.91
Enter y for yesy
Total is 80.91
Enter the amount of sales933
Enter commission rate.04
commission is 37.32
Enter y for yesy
Total is 37.32
Enter the amount of sales9909
Enter commission rate.10
commission is 990.9000000000001
Enter y for yesn
Total is 990.9000000000001
You have exited the program. Thet total is 990.9000000000001
>>> 

> Blockquote
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot figure it out

Comment: Where do you think its going wrong? Make sure you write the expected input and output because that is not really explicit always.

Comment: if you are referring to the total not updating its because you are setting it to 0 at the start of each loop. move total=0 outside the loop, just before it starts

Comment: It would be better to do: "keep_going = True" and then later "while keep_going".  If you want to use the "='y' code then you should say "while 'y' in keep_going".

Answer (score 2):

Every time you loop you are setting total to zero. Move your initialization of total to outside of the loop as I show below.

```
#this program calculates sales commissions and sums the total of all sales commissions the user has entered

print("Welcom to the program sales commission loop")

keep_going='y'

total=0
while keep_going=='y':

    #get a salespersons sales and commission rate
    sales=float(input('Enter the amount of sales'))
    comm_rate=float(input('Enter commission rate'))

    #calculate the commission
    commission=sales*comm_rate

    print("commission is",commission)

    keep_going=input('Enter y for yes')

    total=total+commission
    print("Total is",total)

print("You have exited the program. Thet total is",total)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reinitializing 'total' every time you repeat the loop. You don't need to initialize the variable, but in case you want to, you must do it outside the while loop. The corrected code would be:

```
#this program calculates sales commissions and sums the total of all sales commissions the user has entered

print("Welcome to the program sales commission loop")

keep_going='y'
total=0
while keep_going=='y':
    #get a salespersons sales and commission rate
    sales=float(input( 'Enter the amount of sales ' ))
    comm_rate=float(input( 'Enter commission rate ' ))

    #calculate the commission
    comission= sales * comm_rate
    print( "commission is {}".format(comission) )

    keep_going=input('Enter y for yes: ')
    total += comission
    print( "Total is {}".format(total) )

print("You have exited the program. Thet total is",total)
```